# Bridged VirtualBox VM: Is there an internal Host IP address

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I'm running a VirtualBox VM in bridged network mode.

Is there still an *internal* IP address for the Host?

(I don't want traffic to my host going over the bridged network)

To clarify, I do want my VM bridged on the public network, but I also want it to be able to connect to my host, without going out on the public network. Would setting two interfaces (one bridged, one host-only) solve this? Would I then have to configure the routing table?

Comment: I think that **bridged** network is the one where host and guests share the network. I think that **internal** network may be the one that you need. see https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

Comment: @richard but on internal network my VM won't be bridged to the network. I would like to have my VM bridged on the public network but also (if possible) hit the host without going out on the public network. I guess what I would need is two interfaces, one host-only and one bridged, my issue is configuring the routing table after.

Comment: If your guest talks to the host on the public IP address then traffic won't actually leave the machine; it'll still stay on the bridge.

Comment: If you want good clear answers, then provide a good clear question: The problem with providing good answers is often not a technical one, but knowing what you want to do.

Comment: The host-only adapter will use net 192.168.56.0/24 by default. You can change it in Settings. You can have the addresses assigned by a built in DHCP server or assign them statically. To access your host from the guest without going through the public network, just use its 192.168.56 address.